# ESLint with React gives `no-unused-vars` errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, eslint

I've setup `eslint` & `eslint-plugin-react`.

When I run ESLint, the linter returns `no-unused-vars` errors for each React component.

I'm assuming it's not recognizing that I'm using JSX or React syntax. Any ideas?

Example:

**app.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Header from './header.js';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header />
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Linter Errors:**

```
/my_project/src/components/app.js
  1:8  error  'React' is defined but never used   no-unused-vars
  2:8  error  'Header' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars
```

**Here is my `.eslintrc.json` file:**

```
{
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es6": true
    },
    "extends": "eslint:recommended",
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "experimentalObjectRestSpread": true,
            "jsx": true
        },
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "plugins": [
        "react"
    ],
    "rules": {
        "react/jsx-filename-extension": [1, { "extensions": [".js", ".jsx"] }],
        "indent": [
            "error",
            2
        ],
        "linebreak-style": [
            "error",
            "unix"
        ],
        "quotes": [
            "error",
            "single"
        ],
        "semi": [
            "error",
            "always"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: You're importing `React` while not using it, you're just using `Component`, which is correctly imported.

Comment: That makes sense - but why would `Header` also have the error? (You actually need to import React, otherwise when the JSX gets transpiled, it will give an error)

Comment: This shouldn't be happening by now. What's your eslint version?
 https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/1905

Answer (score 280, accepted):

First, install the following module `npm install --save-dev eslint-plugin-react`.

Then, in your `.eslintrc.json`, under `extends`, include the following plugin:

```
'extends': [
    'plugin:react/recommended'
]
```

[Source](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react)

Comment: Great answer.Of course you should do first (npm install --save-dev eslint-plugin-react)

Comment: What about if your using airbnb? I tried adding 'plugin:react/recommended' before but it didn't work

extends: [
    "plugin:react/recommended",
    "airbnb",
    "airbnb/hooks",
    "plugin:react-redux/recommended",
    "plugin:prettier/recommended",
    "prettier/react",
  ],

Comment: Here's the authoritative documentation ...

https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react#recommended

Comment: A quibble, if this is in a json file (`.eslintrc.json`), shouldn't those by double quotes?

Comment: I have my eslintrc extending `plugin:react/recommended`, but it still gives me this warning. I think it's because I'm using React in a file with a simple .js extension. When I give the file a .jsx extension, the warning goes away.

Answer (score 78):

To solve this only problem without adding new rules from `react/recommended` install `eslint-plugin-react`:

```
npm install eslint-plugin-react --save-dev
```

add in `.eslintrc.js`:

```
"plugins": ["react"]
```

and:

```
"rules": {   
     "react/jsx-uses-react": "error",   
     "react/jsx-uses-vars": "error" 
}
```

Comment: This isn't working for me, I'm still getting a warning from no-unused-vars

Comment: Works for me with VScode

Answer (score 32):

## Quickest fix

To ignore all TitleCase variables, add this to your ESLint config:

```json
{
    "rules": {
        "no-unused-vars": [
            "error",
            {
                "varsIgnorePattern": "React"
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

## Correct fix

Use [eslint-plugin-react](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react) to ignore React variables.

```bash
npm install eslint-plugin-react -D
```

Add this to your ESLint config:

```json
{
    "plugins": [
        "react"
    ],
    "rules": {
        "react/jsx-uses-vars": "error",
        "react/jsx-uses-react": "error"
    }
}
```

## Suggested fix

Use [eslint-plugin-react](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react) to improve your JSX usage, not just to silence this error.

```bash
npm install eslint-plugin-react -D
```

Add this to your ESLint config:

```json
{
    "extends": [
        "plugin:react/recommended"
    ]
}
```

---

If you use [XO](https://github.com/xojs/xo), refer to [eslint-config-xo-react](https://github.com/xojs/eslint-config-xo-react).

Comment: If you want to use the `varsIgnorePattern` modifier you could simply just put `React` as the pattern. At least in my case, the issue was that I am importing React in every file and my linter is complaining if I use functional components etc. Someone more experienced than I am might be able to tell me if that could cause unanticipated issues.

Comment: Good suggestion. I was thinking about ignoring all JSX components, but that's not necessary.

Answer (score 19):

Since I found this while googling, you should know that this simple rule is enough to prevent this message:

```
react/jsx-uses-react
```

The `react/recommended` set of rules adds [many other rules](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react#recommended) you may not want.

Answer (score 14):

In my case I needed to add in your `.eslintrc.js`:

```
'extends': [
    'plugin:react/recommended'
]
```

plus a specific tweaking to rid of preact import: `import { h } from 'preact'` but you can use this example to get rid of your specific warnings like so:

```
    "no-unused-vars": [
        "error",
        {
            "varsIgnorePattern": "^h$"
        }
    ],
```

Answer (score 8):

**2022**

If you're using ESLint with more configurations, be careful about the order of `extends` property array.

```
{
    extends: [
        'eslint:recommended',
        'plugin:react/jsx-runtime',
        'plugin:react/recommended',
        'plugin:prettier/recommended',
        'prettier',
      ],
      plugins: ['react'],

   //...
}
```

For example, make sure that you place `'plugin:react/recommended'` after any other react configuration. Place `'react'` as a plugin as well, and if you're using prettier make sure that you're following a proper configuration.

Comment: This helped me resolve the unused React var eslint issue.I moved 'plugin:react/jsx-runtime' before 'plugin:react/recommended' as suggested and issue got resolved. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in `.eslintrc.js`

```
"rules": {   
 "react/jsx-uses-react": 2,   
 "react/jsx-uses-vars": "error" 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my situation error was **correct**. React was defined but not used. Got me confused.

Answer (score -1):

I have the same error as well as I started to learn React yesterday. The terminal show the error and it is pretty straightforward to ignore the unused variable error.

Error from the terminal:

```
Line 5:17:  'setBlog' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars
Search for the keywords to learn more about each warning.
```

Just add `// eslint-disable-next-line` this line before the variable which you have the error of unused variable. Like,

```
// eslint-disable-next-line
const [blogs, setBlog] = useState(... my code)
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem either. It just hides it from you. From my perspective it does not look like a solution to the problem

Comment: This is an awful "solution"

Answer (score -1):

in eslintrc.js
adding following will solve the error

```
  plugins: [
    'react/recommended',
  ],

  rules: {
    "react/jsx-uses-react": "error",   
     "react/jsx-uses-vars": "error" 
  },
```

Answer (score -1):

```
1st install npm 
npm install --save-dev eslint-plugin-react

In Package.json replace eslintConfig declaration

"eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ],
    "plugin":"react/recommended",
    "rules": {
      "react/jsx-uses-react": "error",   
       "react/jsx-uses-vars": "error" 
    }
  },
```

Answer (score -2):

If you create the project throught create-react-app CLI,You can `npm run eject`,and edit the package.json "eslintConfig" field,like this:

```
`"eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app",
    "rules": {
      "eqeqeq": "off",
      "no-unused-vars": "off",
    }
  },`
```

the eslint will be closed

Answer (score -2):

if you are using Create-react-app, there is no need to install anything or Eject, the simple solution is:

since the `no-unused-vars-errors` is thrown from `webpackHotDevClient.js`, you just need to go to `/node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.dev.js.`
on "new ESLintPlugin" rules just add :

```
'react/jsx-uses-react': 'error',
'react/jsx-uses-vars': 'error',
'no-unused-vars': 0
```

Comment: Even if this is the approach `eslint-plugin-react` [uses](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-uses-vars.md), the best way to "fix" these eslint warnings when using react is actually using the react plugin, or other warnings will arise sooner or later.

Answer (score -5):

According to [Official Docs of Eslint](https://eslint.org/docs/2.13.1/user-guide/configuring#:%7E:text=To%20disable%20rule%20warnings%20in,*%2F%20alert(%27foo%27)%3B) have you tried this

`/* eslint no-unused-vars : "off" */`

add this line as it is inside anywhere in your code. Hopefully you warning may go away and it may help you

Comment: I don't think this is the right approach. It doesn't solve the answer, it just hides it..

Comment: Even if this is the approach `eslint-plugin-react` [uses](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-uses-vars.md), the best way to "fix" these eslint warnings when using react is actually using the react plugin, or other warnings will arise sooner or later.