# ESLint validate JSX file

Tags: reactjs, jsx, eslint

I use ESLint to check my react code. However, it cannot identify the variable in react component tag. ESLint throw the error 'no-unused-vars' to me(the variable 'Comp'). But I have been used this variable in my code

```
export function TestHoc() {
    return function (Comp) {
        class testHocComponent extends PureComponent{
            render(){
                const props={
                    'x':1,
                    'y':2,
                    'z':3
                };

                return (
                    <Comp {...props}/>
                );
            }
        }
        return testHocComponent;
    };
}
```

And here is the configuration of my ESLint

```
"env": {
    "browser": true,
    "commonjs": true,
    "es6": true,
    "node": true
},
"parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 6,
    "ecmaFeatures": {
        "experimentalObjectRestSpread": true,
        "jsx": true,
        "arrowFunctions": true,
        "classes": true,
        "modules": true,
        "defaultParams": true
    },
    "sourceType": "module"
},
"parser": "babel-eslint",
"plugins": [
    "react"
],
```

Comment: First of all, instead of the images, try pasting the code.

Comment: Sorry about that, it's my fault

Comment: `"rules": {
  "react/jsx-uses-vars": 2
}`
May be this can help you out

Comment: thx, i'm new at ESLint, I will try this way

Comment: Add full lint file here, so that one can help easily and please let me know if still there is some issue after adding the rule..

Comment: I just copy the rules from the ESLint documents and do some setting. It's too long to add full lint file here. maybe I should find some plugin to help me

Comment: Added it as answer, you can accept and upvote I think.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ESLint with React gives \`no-unused-vars\` errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42541559/eslint-with-react-gives-no-unused-vars-errors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `{rules": { "react/jsx-uses-vars": 2 }` can help you out. You can spare some time to read [this](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-uses-vars.md).