# Do you really need to import 'React' when creating hooks? (React-hooks)

Tags: reactjs, eslint, create-react-app, react-hooks

I saw the examples where https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html they always do:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
```

But `React` is not really used in the file, do we really need it and why?

I asked this question because I am encountering an issue with eslint saying:

`'React' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars` - And I'm on create-react-app 3.0.1 which eslint is already included - (and I'm not sure how to fix this - already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42542068/2784493) and also tried adding it on package.json `eslintConfig` but still nothing)

Comment: "But React is not really used in the file" if you have jsx in you code it is actually used. If not you could only import hooks for example if your code contains custom hook definition and does not involve element creation per se.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will need `React` if you are rendering `JSX`.

To avoid that `eslint` warning, you should use [react-in-jsx-scope](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/react-in-jsx-scope.md) rule from [eslint-plugin-react](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react).

In that rule, it also explains why you need `React` in the file, even if you don't use it (you think you don't use it, but if you render `JSX`, you do).

> When using JSX, `<a />` expands to `React.createElement("a")`. Therefore the React variable must be in scope.
>   If you are using the @jsx pragma this rule will check the designated variable and not the React one.

Comment: hmmm I'm using the same rule for my components and it doesn't complain, it only complains on hook files. (Accepted the answer anyways coz it explains why I need to import React, which is the title of this question)

Comment: On hook files, you type `React` and then it gives the warning, in other components, you probably use `React` in `class Foo extends React.Component`

Comment: @IamL what is expected?

Comment: That it will throw a warning on hook files (back on the question above)?

Comment: @IamL yes. You have 2 rules. One that says, `no-unused-vars` and this run your code and check if the variable is used in the code. `react-in-jsx-scope` will look for `React` and check if you use `JSX`, if so, it will override `no-unused-vars` for `React` variable because it knows that later, that `JSX` will use the variable `React` and it transpile. `no-unused-vars` doesn't know that you will transpile your code and use `React` later.

Answer (score 7):

React 17 has a new JSX transform which no longer requires the import (also backported to new versions 16.14.0, 15.7.0, and 0.14.10). You can read more about it here:
https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/09/22/introducing-the-new-jsx-transform.html

```
// no import needed
const App = () => <div>hello!</div>
```

However, you still need to import to use hooks:

```
import { useState } from 'react'

const App = () => {
  const [stuff, setStuff] = useState('stuff')

  return <div>{stuff}</div>
}
```

The docs also link to a script to automatically update all of the files in a project to fix all of the imports. Personally, I was in the habit of just using the `React.useWhatever` form so I never needed to mess with the import statement, but using named imports can potentially reduce the final bundle size.

The docs say the named import is now the recommended way, so this is NOT recommended, but if you really want to keep the `React` import, you can set the below eslint rule to stop it from complaining. Note that this will continue to require it in all files.

```
"react/jsx-uses-react": "error"
```

Answer (score 3):

From the React official docs:

> Fundamentally, JSX just provides syntactic sugar for the
>   `React.createElement(component, props, ...children)` function. The JSX
>   code:
>
> `<MyButton color="blue" shadowSize={2}>Click Me</MyButton>`
>
> compiles
>   into:
>
> ```
> React.createElement(MyButton, {color: 'blue', shadowSize: 2},'Click Me' )
> ```
>
> You can also use the self-closing form of the tag if
>   there are no children. So:
>
> ```
> <div className="sidebar" />
> ```
>
> compiles into:
>
> ```
> React.createElement('div', {className: 'sidebar'}, null )
> ```

https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html

**EDIT** Hooks are also under the React namespace, React.useState ...etc

Comment: Your answer applies in the case that there is JSX in the file, but in the custom hooks example referenced by OP, there is no JSX in the file.