# how to solve this no-unused-vars error in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I am creating a todo app using MERN stack.I am new to MERN stack technology and I kindly neeed your help solving this error.I have provided the code for my app.js file and todo.js file.I can't clearly find the solution of this error anywhere on the internet.
I am getting this error while runnng the node js app using npm start command.

```
Compiled with warnings.

src\App.js
  Line 4:8:  'Todo' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars

Search for the keywords to learn more about each warning.
To ignore, add // eslint-disable-next-line to the line before.
```

#### App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Todo from './components/Todo.js';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

#### Todo.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios';

 // eslint-disable-next-line

export class Todo extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    
        this.state = {
             todos : [],
             item : ""
        }
    }

    changeHandler = (event) => {
        this.setState({item: event.target.value})
    }

    clickHandler = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault()
        console.log(this.state.item)
        axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: 'http://localhost:3000/',
            data: {
              todo: this.state.item,
            }
          });
        this.setState({item:''})
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('http://localhost:3000/').then((response) => {
            console.log(response.data.data)
            let data = [];
            console.log(response.data.data.length)
            for(var i =0; i < response.data.data.length; i++){
                data.push(response.data.data[i].todo)
            }
            this.setState({todos: data})
        });
    }
    componentDidUpdate() {
        axios.get('http://localhost:3000/').then((response) => {
            console.log(response.data.data)
            let data = [];
            console.log(response.data.data.length)
            for(var i =0; i < response.data.data.length; i++){
                data.push(response.data.data[i].todo)
            }
            this.setState({todos: data})
        });
    }
  
    render() {
        
        return (
            <div>
                <input type="text" onChange={this.changeHandler}/>
                <button type="submit" onClick={this.clickHandler}>add</button>
                <div>
                    <ul>{this.state.todos.map((todo, index) => <li key={index}>{todo}</li>)}</ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Todo
```

Answer (score 0):

That warning you are getting because even though you are importing Todo file in your App.js file but you aren't using it anywhere.Either try using it in App.js or remove the import(in case you don't need it).That should fix the warning.
Or add `// eslint-disable-next-line` just before the import Todo.. statement in App.js

Comment: I have followed a article to make this app and maybe I have missed something because they have included the Todo file.So don't the what's causing the issue.Please guide me further.

Comment: did you try removing the import ? just try it once.and see what you get.

Comment: It is gone,but the thing is I am not getting the todo list app output

Comment: @VihangKale try adding // eslint-disable-next-line just before import Todo statement in App.js.Other than that once you use `Todo` file in your App.js code ,it will disappear.you might also find https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42541559/eslint-with-react-gives-no-unused-vars-errors helpful

Comment: @VihangKale see if you aren't using the import then there is anyways no point in keeping it ,and by using the import you will get rid of the warning.

Comment: https://codeburst.io/hitchhikers-guide-to-back-end-development-with-examples-3f97c70e0073 I used this article to make the app.So kindly check it because I want to that Todo import but something is missing.