# React assigned value but never used in an unexisting file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im using create-react-app to make my aplication. After I save the files to compile the terminal throws the folowing error:
src\App.js
Line 37:21:  'setOpenModal' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars

src\App\App.js
Line 37:21:  'setOpenModal' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars

the thing is, the file App.js I moved to a file called App and changed the name to index.js. Also I sent the variable setOpenModal to a element like so:

src/App/index.js:

```
  const [openModal, setOpenModal] = React.useState(false);

  return (
    <AppIU
      doc_type={doc_type}
      date={date}
      course={course}
      openModal={openModal}
      setOpenModal={setOpenModal}
    />
  );
```

the function setOpenModal is actually being used in another file and I pass the fuction through props. is there a way to make react realice that the variable is being used and that the file src/App.js no longer exists??

I've tried just saving again the file to compile it again expecting the warnig to just go away but it persists. Ive also tryed adding the /* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */ and /* eslint-enable no-unused-vars */ before and after declerign the const but it still does not remove the warning. Also I would like to not jus disable the warnings as I have a tendency to forget about decleared variables :v

Comment: When this happens to me, I usually just shut down the server, close the project and restart my editor.  It doesn't happen often, but sometimes webpack just borks.

Comment: The error isn't pointing to the code sample you added, can you show what's in `App.js` on the referenced line? This linter rule is warning you, when you declare (declare, import, destructure, etc) a name, and you are not using it. It doesn't do any further checks, if the given value is actually being used elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I'd shutdown the server, delete the cache and build files, and then start the development server again.

Answer (score 0):

There was the answer for your issue:

First, install the following module `npm install --save-dev eslint-plugin-react`.

Then, in your `.eslintrc.json`, under extends, include the following plugin:

```
'extends': [
    'plugin:react/recommended'
]
```

[ESLint with React gives `no-unused-vars` errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42541559/eslint-with-react-gives-no-unused-vars-errors)