# 'clientdepositmoney' is assigned a value but never used no-unused-vars

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

I had changed the name of one of my JS files from price2 to deposit, and in `MainRoutes.js` I also changed it, but it's showing me an error that `clientdepositmoney` is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars, but I already assigned!

```
// render - sample page
const ContactUS = Loadable(lazy(() => import('pages/contact-us')));
const clientdepositmoney = Loadable(lazy(() => import('pages/apps/invoice/deposit')));
const UserGuides = Loadable(lazy(() => import('pages/Documentations/client-guide')));

    {
      path: 'invoice',
      children: [
        {
          path: 'deposit',
          element: <clientdepositmoney />
        },
        {
          path: 'dashboard',
          element: <AppInvoiceDashboard />
        },
        {
          path: 'create',
          element: <AppInvoiceCreate />
        },
        {
          path: 'details/:id',
          element: <AppInvoiceDetails />
        },
```

the error message is:

> ERROR in [eslint] src\routes\MainRoutes.js   Line 123:7:
> 'clientdepositmoney' is assigned a value but never used
> no-unused-vars
>
> Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
>
> webpack compiled with 1 error and 1 warning

Comment: You might try the solutions in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42541559/eslint-with-react-gives-no-unused-vars-errors)

Comment: If `clientdepositmoney` is supposed to be a React component it should be capitalized, e.g. `Clientdepositmoney`.